# How to convert hours as a float to a 12h timestamp in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe that contains values such as `8.6`, `9.32`, `9.79`, etc.  These values represent hours and fractions of hours.  For instance, 8.6 hours equates to 08:36am, and 9.79 hours equates to 09:47am.  I'm looking for an easy way to convert these floats into a timestamp.  One approach could be to parse the fractional portion of the float and multiply by 60 to get the number of minutes, then convert to a timestamp.  However, I'm wondering if anyone has a better solution using something like `lubridate` to convert the float to a timestamp.

```
df <- structure(list(start_time = c(8.6, 9.32, 9.79, 10.09, 10.63, 
8.64)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$start_time_hms = hms::as_hms(df$start_time*60*60)

  start_time  start_time_hms
1       8.60 08:36:00.000000
2       9.32 09:19:12.000000
3       9.79 09:47:24.000000
4      10.09 10:05:24.000000
5      10.63 10:37:48.000000
6       8.64 08:38:24.000000
```

Or if you want a POSIXct datetime:

```
df$start_time_hms = lubridate::ymd_hms("2022-06-24 00:00:00") + df$start_time*60*60


  start_time      start_time_hms
1       8.60 2022-06-24 08:36:00
2       9.32 2022-06-24 09:19:12
3       9.79 2022-06-24 09:47:24
4      10.09 2022-06-24 10:05:24
5      10.63 2022-06-24 10:37:48
6       8.64 2022-06-24 08:38:24
```